# "You asked about this job" message has the wrong date

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Back in September, I applied for a job on Careers 2.0. Just yesterday, I posted a question to the employer regarding my application. I now see two messages above the position:

- You applied for this position on Sep 9. Good Luck!
- You asked about this job on Sep 9.

It looks like the "asked about" message is using the wrong date. Oops!

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you ask a question about a job, if you already have a job application then we simply attach your question to that existing application.

So internally, the "date" of your question was just the date you submitted the job application, which didn't make sense.

I've now changed this so we only show a question date if you *don't* already have an application. In your case this means you'll only see the application date on that listing now. If you want to see your question (and the date you sent it), just go to your Messages.